# Task Event using Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow

Is it possible to write an event handler for the finish event of a Task in 2013.

Is it possible to catch the Committed Event of a Task in 2013?

I see there is a WorkflowEventArgs, but I am having a hard time finding the 'subject' of the event.  Would VersionedItem be the correct subject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Task is a process definition with 1 activity, so you need `FinishProcessEventArgs` and subject is a `Process`

Comment: Additionally FinishProcessEventArgs will give you the "Reason" why the process instance finished. The values are, Normal, Terminated, ForcedFinish, you can execute some logic depending on the reason for it.